# Java. Клиент-сервер. Unable to read data from an open socket

Tags: java, serialize, клиент-сервер

При загрузке объекта с сервера выдает данную ошибку:

> Unable to read data from an open socket. java.io.EOFException.

При этом сама загрузка происходит, но затем работа сервера прекращается. Если же записываю объекты на сервер, все в порядке.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как необходимо выполнить вх./вых. потоки, чтобы при этом сервер продолжал ожидать дальнейшие запросы.

```
while (true)
{
    socket = this.serverSocket.accept();
    OutputStream oStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream ouStream = new ObjectOutputStream(oStream);
    ouStream.writeObject(objects);
    InputStream iStream = socket.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(iStream);
    Object tmp  = inStream.readObject();      
    if (tmp!=null)
        objects = (ArrayList<Shape>)tmp;
    inStream.close();
    ouStream.close();
    socket.close();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```